# Do vendor prefixes from https://autoprefixer.github.io/ garantee full browser compatibility?

Tags: flexbox

I want to start using flexbox, but it's not fully accepted by all browsers.

If I use this site:

```
https://autoprefixer.github.io/
```

Can I be 100% sure flexbox will work with ALL broswers? Even ie 8 and older versions?

I heard flexbox has been around since 2009, will it EVER be available on ALL broswers?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#search=flex

Comment: Other than that, no, vendor prefixes is not a time machine that can make a released browser support functionality it never supported.

Comment: So you don't recommend I use or learn flexbox? I want something that works 100%. Is flexbox just  a fad, a trend?

Comment: Arguably there is hardly anything in web area that works 100%. As new features appear, they gradually get support across browsers. You use things like `caniuse.com` to understand what percentage of browsers currently support what you want to use and decide if you want to use it now or wait. Flex is a [W3C Candidate Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35137869/3597276